# Why are cottontail rabbits smelling through gravel piles?

Tags: animal-behaviour, rabbits

In one of the gravel parking lots I pass on my way to work there are a number of cotton tail rabbits that  [hang out there](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/21760/why-would-cottontail-rabbits-be-hanging-out-in-a-gravel-parking-lot). At one end of parking lot there is piled up gravel from all of the plowing that happened over the winter.

A couple of times when I have passed by there **were rabbits that looked like they were going through the piles with their noses trying to find something.**

What could the cottontail rabbits be smelling for?

Comment: Do they use salt on the parking lot or the roads leading to the lot? There may a concentration of salt because the plows moved it there.

Comment: @B540Glenn That's possible it wouldn't be in the lot but it could have happened on the roads around it

Comment: Possibly related:  When our patio was regrouted, the squirrels licked the new grout for several months after.

Comment: @Sue No, there were no holes and it was just gravel

Comment: Thanks Charlie. I posted a comment I hadn't finished writing, so I deleted it to give myself more time to think. You must have seen it in that very short period of time! So that your comment doesn't look out of place, I'll ask it again, even though the question will be below the answer!! Were there any holes in the pile that a bunny could have been looking for in order to get inside?

Comment: I'm going to agree with the salt theory.